# Multiline field displays as single line in a mail send by EmailJS

Tags: reactjs, multiline

I'm trying to send an email with EmailJS in a React web app. One variable has multiple lines, but in the email everything is in one line. Can you help me solve this issue? Here's my code:

```
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  let stopsString = "";

  stops.map((stop, index) => {
    stopsString =
      stopsString +
      `Stop #${index + 1}
      Name: ${stop.name} 
      Address: ${stop.address} 
      Lat: ${stop.lat} Lng: ${stop.lng}` +
      "\n ";
  });
  console.log(stopsString);

  const params = {
    user_email: email,
    user_name: user.username,
    origin: origin.name,
    destination: destination.name,
    stops: stopsString,
  };

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs
      .send("service_id", "template_id", params, "key")
      .then(
        (result) => {
          alert("Email sent successfully");
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.text);
        }
      );
  };
```

The console log displays this:

```
Stop #1
      Name: 76 
      Address: 1480 Broadway, Burlingame, CA 94010, United States 
      Lat: 37.5844622 Lng: -122.3663426
 Stop #2
      Name: IHOP 
      Address: 590 El Camino Real, San Bruno, CA 94066, United States 
      Lat: 37.6253214 Lng: -122.4139147
```

But the email looks like this:

```
Stop #1 Name: 76 Address: 1480 Broadway, Burlingame, CA 94010, United States Lat: 37.5844622 Lng: -122.3663426 Stop #2 Name: IHOP Address: 590 El Camino Real, San Bruno, CA 94066, United States Lat: 37.6253214 Lng: -122.4139147
```

Thank you very much! All the help is appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Since emails usually use a subset of HTML (and whitespace in HTML is usually collapsed), I don't think they treat newlines as line breaks. Instead, you want to use a `<br />` tag in place of the newlines when sending the email:

```js
  let stopsString = "";

  stops.map((stop, index) => {
    stopsString =
      stopsString +
      `Stop #${index + 1} <br/>
      Name: ${stop.name} <br/>
      Address: ${stop.address} <br/>
      Lat: ${stop.lat} Lng: ${stop.lng}` +
      "<br/>";
  });
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help! But it didn't resolve the issue, it just added the <br /> at the end of the string :c

Comment: Oh, maybe your email is in text/plain then; does using `\r\n` instead of `\n` work? (try adding a "\r" to the end of each line in your template string)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work either. Thank you for reaching out!